# Handle multiple views with routing in same HTML page

Tags: html, jquery, jquery-mobile, view, single-page-application

I am building an SPA without a framework and I am stuck on how to manage to show and hide 3 views that I have on the same page and include routing. I found jQuery Mobile that does perfectly the trick with the data-role="page". However, it ruins my css and it's outdated so not expected to work in the near future?

here is how my code looks like :

```
... fixed header ...

<div id="Page1" class="wrapper" data-role="page" data-transition="slide" >
 content view one
</div>

<div id="Page2" class="wrapper" data-role="page" data-transition="slide" >
 content view two
</div>

<div id="Page3" class="wrapper" data-role="page" data-transition="slide" >
 content view three
</div>

... fixed footer where music is playing and want to keep it playing while moving from one page to another ...
```

Any idea how I can achieve this without having to use/learn a framework like react or angular??
thanks in advance

Comment: Does this help? https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/navs/#javascript-behavior

Comment: no it didnt, it just fades tabs ...